# Send mail with the latest file's content if appended

Tags: bash, file-processing, logfile

There is `/var/log/httpd/error_log` file which contains errors from the whole `httpd`.

I want to be able to send those new log via email message if any appears - with for example 15 minutes interval. I would like to use `CRON` to call bash script that will send new content.

Is there any efficience way to obtain, which lines were appended since last check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending a mail, you can store the line count of the file somewhere (e.g., a file), and then use `tail +n` to print only from the n-th line on, like

```
last_linecount=`cat .last_linecount` # or check if file does not exist
wc -l /var/log/httpd/error_log >.last_linecount
tail -n +$((last_linecount + 1)) /var/log/httpd/error_log | whatever
```

You should also check if the current number of lines is lower than `last_linecount`, as then the logfile might have been rotated (if applicable) and you have to combine both the tail on the old logfile and everything from the new logfile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `error_log` as a marker and don't need store line numbers in the external file.

the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING="last_log_check_point_string"
LOGFILE="/opt/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
URL="http://localhost/$STRING"

linenum=$(grep -n "$STRING" $LOGFILE | tail -1 | sed 's/:.*//')
curl "${URL}" >/dev/null 2>&1
[[ ! -z "$linenum" ]] && sed -n "$linenum,\$p" < $LOGFILE | mail -s "error log at $(date)" "your@email.com"
```

- will find the **line number** of the last occurence of `last_log_check_point_string`
- will make an request to your web with nonexistent url what contain your string (so, you get an new notice into the `error_log` - the new `marker_point`)
- every line after the above **line number** will mail to you.

The last line of the error_log will be the new `marker point`, so you have a control how the script works. If you don't have `curl`, use `wget` - or is possible make a request with a pure bash too.

or the variant - you will get email only when some errors occured

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING="last_log_check_point_string"
LOGFILE="/opt/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
URL="http://localhost/$STRING"
TEMPFILE="/tmp/hterror.$$"

linenum=$(grep -n "$STRING" $LOGFILE | tail -1 | sed 's/:.*//')
curl "${URL}" >/dev/null 2>&1
[[ ! -z "$linenum" ]] && sed -n "$linenum,\$p" < $LOGFILE | grep -v "$STRING" >$TEMPFILE
[[ -s "$TEMPFILE" ]] && mail -s "error log at $(date)" "your@email.com"  < $TEMPFILE
rm -f "$TEMPFILE"
```